# Iris decision tree in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, decision-tree

i am trying to learn about decision trees and I ended up finding a article about decision trees. The goal of the article is to decide if a flower is a iris flower or not but i seem to run into some errors that i hope somebody got the answer to i get two errors like the following:

iris: Bunch iris: inner_f Instance of 'tuple' has no 'target' member

and

iris: Bunch iris: inner_f Instance of 'tuple' has no 'data' member

i get these errors at the x = iris.data line and at the y = iris.target line.

Here is the code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#load iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data
y = iris.target
d = [{"sepal_length":row[0], 
      "sepal_width":row[1], 
      "petal_length":row[2], 
      "petal_width":row[3]} for row in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(d) # construct dataframe
df["types"] = y # assign types
df = df.sample(frac=1.0) # random shuffle rows
df.head()
```

Is there anybody that knows why i get these errors?

Comment: This code did not yield any errors for me.

Comment: Depending on what version your `sklearn` is, there is an argument for `return_X_y`. Please check what type of data you are getting from `load.iris()`. Is it a tuple or a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that the problematic value `iris` is a tuple, which doesn't have the attributes you're referencing. Check the documentation for the tools you're using; they should explain how to unpack `datasets.load_iris()` into the objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would not filter warnings in most cases, as you get useful information from the warnings.

So, the sklearn datasets format is a Bunch, which is a specialized container object that works like a dictionary. You can access it with dot notation, e.g. iris.data or dictionary notation, e.g. iris['data']. Here, it is unclear what the error is on your machine, as I (like other commenters) had no problem accessing iris.data or iris['data'] in python 3.8.5.

I wanted to let you know a couple of places to improve your approach:

(1) It is unclear why you need to construct a dataframe as you can get the samples you need directly from calling train_test_split on the concatenated numpy arrays or you can get a random sample of indices from the numpy arrays directly.

(2) Your method for constructing the dataframe is more complex than it needs to be.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# load iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# train test split
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target)

# random shuffle of data/target indices
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng_size = iris.data.shape[0]
idx_sample = rng.choice(np.arange(rng_size), size=rng_size, replace=False)

# simpler way to create dataframe
# concatenate along the columns (axis 1)
# then set the column names in one place
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(iris.data), pd.DataFrame(iris.target)], axis=1)
df.columns = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "types"]
```